# change BorderBrush on Focus of TextBox in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

### Issue

---

I have been trying to change the BorderBrush of my TextBox on Focus for a couple of days now and it does not want to work.

I have written some code that people have suggested but the Border only seems to change on 'Right-Click' of the TextBox and not on Focus?

Here the code I have written:

```
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ServerURL, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Padding="2" BorderThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" FontFamily="Sans Serif" Foreground="#858585" FontSize="10px" FontWeight="Medium">
            <TextBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="2"/>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Resources>
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
```

Like I mentioned it does work when i Right Click the TextBox, but I need it to work on Left Click (When the TextBox is Focused).

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want it to be that way on every instance of `TextBox` or just a single instance? You could overwrite `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Focus.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>` resource, or you could create a custom style template to ensure you keep all the other triggers, or you could do it at the instance like @AnjumSKhan shows below.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this behaviour, the Border colors red on Focus. Are you using MahApps or other styling utilities, a custom Template,...?

Comment: This is a duplicate post of this (your own post!): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536459/xaml-textbox-change-border-color-on-focus

Answer (score 0):

The TextBox control has a "Focused" visual state trigger built-in, you could change the values of that trigger, it's actually pretty simple just follow these steps:

Step 1. add a textbox to your page.

step 2. right click on your textbox and pick : "EditTemplate" \ "Edit a Copy..."

this will take you to the template designer stage.

step 3. check this image: https://postimg.org/image/ocdn34is1/

Answer (score -1):

Apply [`FocusVisualStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744790(v=vs.100).aspx) .

```
<Window.Resources>
       <Style x:Key="ControlStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
       </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<TextBox  FocusVisualStyle="{DynamicResource ControlStyle1}" Text="{Binding ServerURL, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Padding="2" BorderThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" FontFamily="Sans Serif" Foreground="#858585" FontSize="10px" FontWeight="Medium"/>
```

Comment: Why is there an Upvote when the Example isnt even working?